# C++ Create and Add items to listbox

Tags: c++, windows, list, listbox, controls

Sorry for this noob question but i'm new to C++ (coming from C#).  I have a list of items from an array that i want to display on a listbox (just do display - nothing else).  Adding a control in c++ was a lot harder than i thought.

Here's what i have so far:  I'm not sure how to proceed from here and how to get it to work.  Thanks in advance.

```
// .rh file
#define IDC_LISTDIR                 106

//in the .rc file
CONTROL "ListBox", IDC_LISTDIR, "listbox", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_GROUP, 8, 80, 200, 60

//main
SendMessage(HANDLE, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)L"Add This Text to listbox");
```

Also, i'm getting this: 
error C2275: 'HANDLE' : illegal use of this type as an expression

```
IDD_MAINWINDOW DIALOG 36, 54, 421, 252
EXSTYLE WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
CAPTION "Listbox Test"
FONT 9, "MS Sans Serif"
{   
    CONTROL "&OK", IDOK, "button", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 100, 5, 40, 14
    CONTROL "&Cancel", IDCANCEL, "button", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_TABSTOP, 100, 30, 30, 14
    CONTROL "CheckBox", IDC_YESNO, "button", BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_GROUP, 9, 55, 77, 22
    CONTROL "ListBox", IDC_LISTDIR, "listbox", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | WS_VSCROLL | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | WS_GROUP, 8, 80, 200, 60
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SendMessage()` takes an `HWND` to send the message to.  `HANDLE` is a type, not an `HWND` variable.  You need the actual `HWND` of the ListBox at runtime.  Use [`GetDlgItem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdlgitem) to get that, eg:

```c
HWND hwndLB = GetDlgItem(hwndDlg, IDC_LISTDIR);
SendMessage(hwndLB, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, (LPARAM)L"Add This Text to listbox");
```

Where `hwndDlg` is the `HWND` of the window that the ListBox is a child of.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your reply.  I guess what i'm having a hard time understanding is the "hwnDlg".  I edited the post to show the Window that the ListBox is a child of.  How do i create the HWND to that?  Thanks!

Comment: All you showed is the resource that defines your main window, but you did not show how you are actually creating and using that window.  But, you should have access to that window's `HWND` from inside your dialog proc, where I assume you are calling `SendMessage()` from to begin with? It is hard to answer your question without a [mcve].